# $_SESSION variables in php 5.3 not sticking

Tags: php, session

In a server upgrade from 5.2.17 to 5.3.13 my $_SESSION variables are no longer being passed from page to page.

In page 1, I'm setting $_SERVER["isLoggedIn"] = true and in page 2 I'm testing, but find all $_SESSION variables are unset.

I've cut down the code for a simple example as follows:
login.html:

```
<?php
session_start();
    $_SESSION["isLoggedIn"] = true;
    $_SESSION['visitorLanguage']  = "en" ; 


    if ($_SESSION["isLoggedIn"]  == true ){
        print "<p> Log in successful. </p>";
        print "<script>window.location='index.html? lang=".$_SESSION['visitorLanguage']." '</script>";
        }

?>
```

index.html:

```
<?
session_start();
echo "Version: ".phpversion(); 
echo " Session Data: "; 
echo "Is logged in: " . $_SESSION["isLoggedIn"]. "<br/>";
echo "Visitor Language: " . $_SESSION["visitorLanguage"];
?>
```

Returns:

```
Version: 5.3.13 Session Data: Is logged in: 
Visitor Language
and in 5.2:
Version: 5.2.17 Session Data: Is logged in: 1
Visitor Language: en
```

Comment: what are you getting by print_r($_SESSION) show us

Comment: print_r($_SESSION) returns an empty array.

Comment: You didn't post your solution. I needed the answer today.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem to this just cost me about 3 days, make sure to comment out **request_order = None** or set to "**GPCS**" in php.ini or session variables will not be added to the super global array REQUEST.

Comment: Now that looks very interesting. I will give it a go and report back. The PHP manual is a little obscure about the values request_order can have. I deduce that "GPCS" invokes the order Get, Post, Cookies, but I don't understand the "S". It's a bit tricky to test as I'm running on a hosted server with a number of live applications relying on session variables. Switching to 5.3 to test the setting change will disable my users:-( . I just hope they will be forgiving!

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, a page that doesn't have a name ending in .php should not go to the php processor at all. It is more of a mystery that it works in 5.2 than that it does not work in 5.3. In short, make your index page index.php, be sure to delete index.html on the server (and also locally, you do not want it getting uploaded again)... and all should be well. To answer your question, an installation of 5.2 is one installation and an installation of 5.3 is some other installation. One may be set up with different options to the other.

Comment: Hi Geoff,
No, there really is no requirement for PHP code to reside in a file with a .php extension. Indeed, your claim that ".., should not go to the php processor...", rather begs the question of why it does, because it certainly does! 
And no, not surprisingly, changing my index.html to index.php didn't solve the issue. 
If you're not sure, it's quite a good idea to actually test an answer before posting.

Comment: Not sure how I can test anything on your server, Starttrax? I haven't found a way to stop sessions working in 5.3 yet, so please be sure to share when you find out.